# Is there a way to repeat previous searches in tmux scroll buffer?

Tags: tmux

In tmux, when you type `/` in copy mode, you get a prompt `Search Down: xxx` where xxx is the most recent search performed in that same pane.  Is it possible to access the history of previous searches?  ie, I am looking for a plugin (or patch) that will *not* display `xxx` unless I request it (say, with up-arrow), and that makes it possible to access older searches and searches from other panes.  Is similar functionality available?